# Creating a pop up that includes a php query inside

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, popup

Scenario:

You are playing a text-based MMORPG and you are in a crew.
You want to invite someone to your crew, so you type their name into a box, click 'Invite' and a popup appears displaying how much it will cost to invite this person to your crew. On this pop-up you can either accept to pay this amount of decline paying this amount.

I need to run a MySQL query using the username typed in the box, that then displays this inside the popup.

Then when the Accept button is clicked, another query will need to be run.

```
    <center>Username: <input type=text name=invitename class=ttext>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"> <input type="button" class="tbox" value="Go">
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">This will cost *query output here*<br> <input type=submit name=invite class=tbox value="Accept"></span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, without the click actually running any php, I can't output information inside the popup.

So, how do I create a popup that has an echo of a query output, that was created from the username that was input on submit?

Comment: You need to use jquery / javascript to do a request to the server, process it with php, and return data with a json to get parsed on client. If you post more info about your code and your tried solution we can help you to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click of invite button get the user name typed in the text box and append it to a div on pop up. then call a function to execute MySQL query to get the cost to invite this person to your crew.

Insert this value to a hidden field and also to the div to show on popup using java script.

Then at pay/cancel run another function to execute MySQL query for pay or cancel.

Comment: Do you have any examples?